# Is AC power really worth it anymore? Is it time (or almost time) to switch to DC?

Tags: electrical

Houses have historically only offered AC power throughout, but I'm wondering if that makes any sense anymore.  If I were building a large addition, or even building a new home from scratch, would it make sense to build with only AC power?

Let's think about the main things we have in the house that use power.

- LED lights: the bulbs have to convert the AC to DC.  Why not just use DC to begin with?  Of course this means buying new bulbs, which may be expensive, or altering the existing ones, which may be time-consuming...
- Laptops, phones, tablets: again, they have to convert to DC power, which seems silly and inefficient.  Of course I'd need DC cords for all laptops...
- Refrigerators: I don't know what form of power they actually use, but I've seen DC versions available at a much higher price, so this may be one reason to at least not get rid of AC completely.  Maybe.

Those seem to be the main things.  I don't need hair dryers or toasters, and can use gas for most other major appliances.

Now let's say I'm going to try to power the addition (or new house) completely with solar panels.  Suddenly any difference in efficiency has a much more noticeable effect on what I'm paying for the panels.  Would it make sense in this case to use DC for almost everything, if not everything, even if it didn't make sense previously?

---

*** UPDATE ***

While at first glance this may appear the same as [another question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/7430/8868), anyone who takes the time to actually read both of them can see that they are very different.  That other question is looking toward the past and asking why things came to be the way they are.  My question is looking toward the future and asking if it makes sense to change.  In that sense they are the opposite.  Therefore this question should be reopened.

Comment: small kitchen appliances, TVs, stereos, vacuum cleaners, washing machines, tools, fans, microwave ovens, coffee makers.  Too many things yet to be DC friendly to go 100% DC low voltage

Comment: Good points, but many of those I don't use, and I could use a power inverter for the occasions where I need to use them.  I have never owned a TV, I haven't owned a stereo since a decade before the last turn of the century.  I'd be happy to do without a vacuum and just use a broom.  I'd guess my DeWalt drill is really using DC since it is powered by batteries.  The microwave, however, would be hard to live without...

Comment: It's still the same question with the same answer. AC is cheaper. It can be transformed almost losslessly, and it can therefore be transmitted in the form of high voltage/low current, which uses much less copper, even within a single house. There is also the question of where your DC TV, stereo, washing machine, etc etc are going to come from and whether the market is (ever) going to supply them at a competitive price.

Comment: [HVDC transmission is currently in use.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current)

Comment: EJP: while there may be some overlap in the information about AC & DC in the answers, it is ***clearly*** and ***irrefutably*** not the same question.

Comment: Even if this was different enough to be its own question, I still feel like it's off topic.  You're looking to start a discussion, not for a definitive answer.